# Selection of the best concurrency approach

Tags: java, concurrency

I have two separate services.

I get list of strings from 1st service - about 700 values. And then I filter this list and get 100 strings. Then I compose small queries containing 10 of those strings and send they synchronously to the 2nd service. And when I get response from the 2nd service (currently it all is done synchronously - I wait while 2nd service returns response) as another list of strings and add these values into final list.

I wanted to enhance concurrency of this work. I want to send small queries to the 1st server concurrently, get responses on these queries, filter them, and as I get 10 needed filtered values, I compose and send query to the 2nd service (also concurrently). And after 2nd service returns response, I add this response (list of strings) to a final list (as far as I understand, I should use something like synchronized block).

Is there any good ways to implement this logic without low level and ugly Threads? I've almost never worked with concurrency in Java so I don't know this part of the language very good.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would [start here](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html); beyond that you are going to need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Could you provide more details about the word "services"? What kind of  service? Based on which protocol(eg. HTTP)? Will it be bottleneck after you change your caller from single thread to concurrent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no framework more suitable for this task than good old threads. The problem with threads is that they are taught with synchronized keyword from the start, while in most cases, it can be avoided. Use BlockingQueues whenever possible, and your program would be clean and understandable.

The structure of your program can be as follows:

```
T1->Q1->TP1->Q2->T2->Q3->TP2->Q4->T3
```

Thread T1 (it can be the main thread) splits input list into small queries and puts them into queue Q1.
Thread Pool TP1 is just a number of threads, each of which takes queries from Q1, access the service 1 and puts the result into queue Q2.
Thread T2 takes the responses from Q2, filters them, packs in batches of 10 and puts into Q3.
Thread Pool TP2 sends queries from Q3 to the 2nd service and puts results into Q4.
Thread T3 forms the final list.